# Processing Android video frame by frame while recording Android 4

Tags: android, gps, record, video-processing

I'm attempting to make an app, that records video, and "embeds" the current gps-coordinates in the recorded video.

But I can't seem to find a way of adding the text to the frames while recording.

My target version is 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OpenCv library

http://opencv.org/downloads.html

It's an image processing library that allows you to do lots of cool with your frame.

Also, if you look at their provided sample projects there is one project that is doing exactly what you just described.

Comment: Do you know any way to do this without using OpenCV? I think it's a little bit too "heavy" for doing this task ^)

Comment: @BorisVasilyev Is it "little bit" or "too" heavy? :p